# Print output from a variable not part of for loop

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I have a for loop that joins every three lines of output together

```
for n in range(len(z)//3):
    l.append(''.join(z[n*3:n*3+3]))
    test = "\n".join(l)
print test
```

Z is a list of text, I also have another variable not part of the for loop but used elsewhere in my code I would like to print this variable along with test per line for example:

```
z = ['red', 'or', 'black', 'odd', 'or', 'even', 'yes', 'or', 'no']
```

The output of test is

```
red or black
odd or even
yes or no
```

I would like to add another variable to the print say for example the variable is "u" which has the text "you decide?" In it so I would the output to be:

```
red or black you decide?
odd or even you decide?
yes or no you decide?
```

When I print test, `u` it only prints `u` in the last line rather than every line.

Comment: please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 4):

Just make the change in the line, `l.append(''.join(z[n*3:n*3+3]))` using the function [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

```
l.append("{} you decide?".format(' '.join(z[n*3:n*3+3])))
```

The complete program

```
z = ['red', 'or', 'black', 'odd', 'or', 'even', 'yes', 'or', 'no']
l = []
u = "you decide?"
for n in range(len(z)//3):
    l.append("{} {}".format(' '.join(z[n*3:n*3+3])),u)
    test = "\n".join(l)
print test
```

And the output

```
red or black you decide?
odd or even you decide?
yes or no you decide?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l.append(''.join(z[n*3:n*3+3]) + u) # concatenate the message string
```